# How to show the sum total of a user using select query in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am having two tables one to store the contact details of the user (contact table) and other to store the daily transaction of the user (daybook table). daybook table consist of a the contact_id which acts as a FK.I have used select query with inner join to get all user individual total amount but the query is not showing the result of all user can anyone tell me what is wrong in the query.

Contact table:

```
name: 'contacts',
  columns: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'integer primary key', default: ''},
    { name: 'name', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'mobile_no', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'location', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'type', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'user_id', type: 'integer', default: ''},
    { name: 'is_deleted', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'is_synced', type: 'text', default: ''}
  ]
},
```

Daybook table:

```
{
  name: 'daybook',
  columns: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'integer', default: ''},
    { name: 'date', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'user_type', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'amount_in', type: 'numeric', default: 'default 0'},
    { name: 'amount_out', type: 'numeric', default: 'default 0'},
    { name: 'other_amount', type: 'numeric', default: 'default 0'},
    { name: 'user_id', type: 'integer', default: ''},
    { name: 'description', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'transaction_type', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'sub_category', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'contact_id', type: 'integer', default: ''},
    { name: 'category', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'count', type: 'integer', default: ''},
    { name: 'cost', type: 'integer', default: ''},
    { name: 'bill_no', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'farmer_id', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'is_deleted', type: 'text', default: ''},
    { name: 'is_synced', type: 'text', default: ''}
  ]
},
```

Query used:

```
SELECT contacts.name, IFNULL(SUM(daybook.amount_in),0) AS amount_in, IFNULL(SUM(daybook.amount_out),0) AS amount_out, IFNULL(SUM(daybook.other_amount),0) AS other_amount FROM daybook INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = daybook.contact_id WHERE daybook.user_type = ? AND daybook.user_id = ?;'
```

Result which needed is :

```
Name               amount_in                   amount_out                other_amout

  Sankar                 50000                               0                              3000
```

Comment: Is your query returning an error?  What is the issue?

Comment: it shows only one user name and sums all the total from daybook

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.name, COALESCE(SUM(db.amount_in), 0) AS amount_in, 
       COALESCE(SUM(db.amount_out), 0) AS amount_out,  
       COALESCE(SUM(db.other_amount), 0) AS other_amount
FROM daybook db INNER JOIN
     contacts c
     ON c.id = db.contact_id
WHERE db.user_type = ? AND db.user_id = ?
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Note other changes:

- `COALESCE()` rather than `IFNULL()`.  The former is the ANSI standard function.
- The use of table aliases.  This makes queries easier to write and to read.